# Convert XCodeProj to Package.swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I have recently inherited a swift project and would prefer to do my development on a Linux VM, rather then the under powered Mac I have. I have found lots of tutorials on how to got from a Package.swift to a xcodeproj. But I haven't found anything to go the other direction (xcodeproj to Package.swift). It seems that I need the Package.swift to be able to use the swift cli (swift build).

1. Is there a way to build without the Package.swift file?
2. Is there a way to do this that I haven't found?
3. Is there a technical reason that we can't go from a xcodeproj to a Package.swift?

Comment: Is the project an app (using either UIKit or AppKit)?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist The project is a library that is then consumed by other apps. I know the app libraries haven't been migrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1./2. 
A Package.swift file is internally translated to a set of `swiftc` commands. 
If you run `swift build -v` (verbose) on a fully working Swift package, you can see the commands that are being run. Using these commands, you may be able to figure out how to compile any collection of Swift sources without a Package.swift.

For a framework, one command could look something like this:

```
swiftc -module-name TestPackage -emit-dependencies -emit-module -c Path/to/Sources/*.swift -Onone -g -enable-testing -j8 -DSWIFT_PACKAGE -DDEBUG -Xfrontend -color-diagnostics
```

When compiling an executable, there may be additional commands to link the standard library, etc.

3.
The feature set of Xcode far exceeds the capabilities of Swift packages (e.g. .app bundles, Storyboards, Metal source files, ObjC, C, C++, etc.)

However, you can convert your command line project to a Swift package by running `swift package init --type library|executable` to create a Package.swift file. You can then specify a `path` parameter for the target in the Package.swift file:

```
.target(name: "YourTarget", path: "Path/To/Your/Swift/Files")
```

Comment: If the ,swift files where spread across multiple folders would I need to add multiple .targets? Or is the path recursive to sub directories as well?  <br/>
  
Is there a way to generate the verbose build from xcode so I can attempt to generate the matching Package.swift?

Comment: 1: You either specify the path to every file manually after the `-c` argument (which is what `swift build` does) and you can use a wildcard pattern like `./**/*.swift`, that recursively goes through directories.

Comment: 2. In Xcode, you can see build reports (cmd+9). Click on one of the reports, then select the desired stage of the build (e.g. "Compile Swift source files" or "Link ...") phase of the build in the report. All the way to the right of the selected line, you should see [this icon](https://i.imgur.com/8eBUmh2.png). Click on it and you will see the commands that are executed in that stage.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that the Xcode build system links platform specific libraries and SDKs. If your package for example depends on Foundation, you need to make sure that it gets linked. I don't have access to a Linux machine right now, so I can't tell you how to do it there.